# How to convert a c string into its escaped version in c?

Tags: c

Is there any buildin function or a alternative simple and fast way of escape a `C` character array that if used with e.g `printf` should yield original character array again.

```
char* str = "\tHello World\n";
char* escaped_str = escape(str); //should contain "\tHello World\n" with char \ ,t.
printf(escaped_str); //should print out [TAB]Hello World[nextline] similar to if str was printed.
```

Is there a simple way in c to escape a string with c escape characters.

#### Update

I have buffer containing a string with escape character. And i want to include in a C file. For that i need to escape it so it can be complied. I just need to know if there is simple way of doing it instead of scanning the buffer for \n \t etc and generating there c escape char.

```
for(int i=0; i< strlen(buffer);i++)
    if(buffer[i]=='\n')
      sprintf(dest,"\\n")
    else ....
```

#### Update 2

I wrote this function. It work fine.

```
char* escape(char* buffer){
    int i,j;
    int l = strlen(buffer) + 1;
    char esc_char[]= { '\a','\b','\f','\n','\r','\t','\v','\\'};
    char essc_str[]= {  'a', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', 'v','\\'};
  char* dest  =  (char*)calloc( l*2,sizeof(char));
    char* ptr=dest;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        for(j=0; j< 8 ;j++){
            if( buffer[i]==esc_char[j] ){
              *ptr++ = '\\';
              *ptr++ = essc_str[j];
                 break;
            }
        }
        if(j == 8 )
      *ptr++ = buffer[i];
    }
  *ptr='\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: what's wrong with printf( "%s", str ); ?

Comment: no i need the escape string. that was just example.

Comment: see compiler convert \t \n etc into ascii equivalent. I have the ascii string i need to escape it.

Comment: Are you after a way of producing strings to be included in C source code? As @Ben answers, `printf()` has nothing to do with backslash escapes.

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer below so that it can be voted on like the other answers, not edit it into your question. (Also, your solution doesn't correctly escape arbitrary control characters like `'\4'` or `'\177'`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't any standard function for creating the source code version of the string.  But you could use the `iscntrl` function to write one, or just use the `switch` keyword.

But, unless your program writes out a C source file intended to be run through the compiler, you don't need to work with escaped strings.  `printf` doesn't process character escape sequences, only variable insertions (`%d`, `%s`, etc)

Specifically, the following produce the same output:

```
printf("\tHello World\n");
```

and

```
const char* str = "\tHello World\n";
printf(str);
```

and

```
const char* str = "\tHello World\n";
printf("%s", str);
```

The second one isn't a good idea, because if `str` contained `%` your program would produce bad output and could crash.

EDIT: For producing the source code version, there are a couple of approaches:

Simpler, but less readable output:

```
if (iscntrl(ch) || ch == '\\' || ch == '\"' || ch == '\'') {
   fprintf(outf, "\\%03o", ch);
}
else
   fputc(ch, outf);
```

More readable results:

```
switch (ch) {
  case '\"':
    fputs("\\\"", outf);
    break;
  case '\'':
    fputs("\\\'", outf);
    break;
  case '\\':
    fputs("\\\\", outf);
    break;
  case '\a':
    fputs("\\a", outf);
    break;
  case '\b':
    fputs("\\b", outf);
    break;
  case '\n':
    fputs("\\n", outf);
    break;
  case '\t':
    fputs("\\t", outf);
    break;
  // and so on
  default:
    if (iscntrl(ch)) fprintf(outf, "\\%03o", ch);
    else fputc(ch, outf);
}
```

Comment: yup that will work. In mean time i wrote mine own too. check that out as well logic is very similar to yours. But it print out actual \n instead of it hex equivalent. but your second solution is very similar

Comment: We both overlooked `"` and `'`, which will really confuse the compiler if you forget to escape them.  Now fixed in my examples.

Comment: @Fraxtil: Thanks for catching the wrong argument order.  Why oh why couldn't the standard library be consistent about putting the stream at the beginning or the end.  (I guess it's at the beginning for varargs functions, and the end for almost all other?)  Anyway, sorry I didn't see your suggestion in time to accept it; it was correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you. And yeah, the standard I/O functions in particular are weird about argument order; your code looked fine to me until I tried it.

Comment: Be careful if you use hexadecimal escape sequences and unescaped hex digits. ``strlen("\x0123456789abcdef")`` is ``1``.

Comment: `isctrl -> iscntrl` as mentioned [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_iscntrl.htm).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: You are correct, that function is spelled with an `n`.  (So was my first paragraph, but not the code -- fixed now)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require the resulting string to be human-readable, and your compile-time character set is the same as your execution character set, then the *simplest* way is to use code point escapes for everything:

```
int print_string_literal(char *s)
{
    putchar('\"');

    while (*s)
    {
        unsigned cp = (unsigned char)*s++;
        printf("\\x%.2x", cp);
    }

    putchar('\"');
}
```

You could finess this some to produce nicer looking strings, but you did ask for something *simple*...

Comment: I think it is wrong to use "(unsigned char)*s++". A string is not necessarily stored in one big sequential memory chunk. It could be broken apart in several chunks stored in different memory locations, so you cannot simply increase the pointer.

Comment: @papajony: An ordinary C string *is* stored in one big sequential memory chunk.  Apart from the fact that this kind of string is assumed unless otherwise specified when discussing C, we also know that's what the questioner had in mind because they used ordinary string literals, `printf()` and `strlen()` in their examples.

Comment: Sorry, you cannot assume this. If you allocate a string with malloc, there is no guarantee that it will be in one sequential memory chunk. That's up to the OS memory management.

Comment: @papajony: You are incorrect.  Whatever happens behind the scenes, the implementation must make it appear as one contiguous block.  This follows from the definitions of `malloc()` and of the additive operators as they apply to pointer types in the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating a string to be used as part of a C source file, then quoting is quite complex (you have to deal with newlines, several other control characters, quotes, backslashes etc). It's much quicker and easier to use the fact that a string is simply an array of integer-like values - rather than

```
char generated_file_str[] = "ABC\n\";
```

generate

```
char generated_file_str[] = {65,66,67,10,0};
```

This is fairly easy to write - something like:

```
printf("char generated_string[] = {");
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", str[i]);
}
printf("0};\n");
```

Answer (score -2):

The only escaping you need to do is replacing each occurrence of "%" with "%%"; "%" is the **ONLY** character that printf treats specially. The "\" escapes have nothing to do with printf; they're part of the C compiler's compile-time processing of string literals.

Comment: With the updated description of your problem (you're trying to escape strings for use in C source, not for printf) my answer is not so useful.

Answer (score -3):

Please checks the paper on [printf](http://byuh.doncolton.com/courses/tut/printf.pdf)

You need to know more about the escape sequences.

Comment: Paper is misleading. The entire first page and part of the second have nothing to do with printf but with the C compiler and string literals.