# Is there a Qt function to (un-)escape (at least) the ASCII formatting characters (d 0..31) in a QString?

Tags: qt, escaping, qstring, control-characters

I don't like reinventing the wheel and this seemed like a pretty basic function.  The same concept as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684976/how-do-i-print-escape-characters-as-characters) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201451/how-to-convert-a-c-string-into-its-escaped-version-in-c) questions except specifically for QStrings?  QRegExp has an escape function so I'm wondering if I've just overlooked the QString version or whether there's a good reason there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there would be such a function built into Qt, as it's really unlikely to be a frequently-required thing to do with QStrings. (Or at least, I can't think of any plausible usage that it would be worth the Qt maintainers supporting.)

`QRegExp::escape()` is a bit different, as it's doing a specific task of escaping characters that are known to have special meaning in regular expressions. Qt provides a method for this because it is a normal and common thing to need to do with regular expressions.

So, I think your best bet is going to be to take one of the example snippets of code that you linked to in the question, and roll your own function.